# Install ms_graph python module

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to install ms_graph python module but had no luck till now,
I have already tried the following command:

> pip install microsoftgraph-python

> python -m pip install msgraph-core

> python -m pip install azure-identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try python3 -m pip install msgraph-core

ref- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=2

Thanks